# Creating Excel Like Pivot in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, grouping

I have table which currently holds sales data based on Territory > Area > Cluster > Region > Segment. What I need is basically get the output which can show rollups at each level at the botton.

```
select 
   TS.Cycle,
   Segment, 
   Region,
   Cluster,
   Area,
   TS.TargetDesc, 
   Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,
   sum(A.Achivement) as ACH, 
   0 as [lvl] 
from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on 
    TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and 
    A.AchivementType='T' and 
    (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by TS.TargetDesc, Area, Cluster, Region, Segment, TS.Cycle
```

Above query give me following output: [base output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAeYk.jpg)

Now as an output what I need is to rollup at each level which

1. Segment
2. Region
3. Cluster
4. Area
5. TargetDesc

I tried using below union of different groupings, but it s creating roll-ups at the top instead of bottom of each level.

```
select 
 TS.Cycle,Segment,Region,Cluster,Area,TS.TargetDesc, Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,sum(A.Achivement) as ACH from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and A.AchivementType='T' and (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by TS.TargetDesc,Area,Cluster,Region,Segment,TS.Cycle
union
select 
 TS.Cycle,Segment,'' as Region,'' as Cluster,'' as Area,'' as TargetDesc, Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,sum(A.Achivement) as ACH from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and A.AchivementType='T' and (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by Segment,TS.Cycle
union
select 
 TS.Cycle,Segment,Region,'' as Cluster,'' as Area,'' as TargetDesc, Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,sum(A.Achivement) as ACH from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and A.AchivementType='T' and (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by Segment,Region,TS.Cycle
union
select 
 TS.Cycle,Segment,Region,cluster,'' as Area,'' as TargetDesc, Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,sum(A.Achivement) as ACH from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and A.AchivementType='T' and (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by Segment,Region,cluster,TS.Cycle
union
select 
 TS.Cycle,Segment,Region,Cluster,Area,'' as TargetDesc, Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,sum(A.Achivement) as ACH from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and A.AchivementType='T' and (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by Segment,Region,Cluster,Area,TS.Cycle
```

Output: [output with union](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS0G5.jpg)

if you see above output rollups are working as desired but they are showing on top of each detail level, instead of bottom.

Need help in doing bottom rollups.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is change your `group by` clause to `group by grouping sets` in your base output query.

[Grouping Sets Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx).

You might have to play around with forcing the `NULL` values to be blanks like you have in your output with union, but the values calculated will match at each level.

**Answer:**

```
select 
   TS.Cycle,
   Segment, 
   Region,
   Cluster,
   Area,
   TS.TargetDesc, 
   Sum(TS.Target) as TGT,
   sum(A.Achivement) as ACH, 
   0 as [lvl] 
from MST_TargetSetup TS
join MST_AchivementSetup A on 
    TS.TargetDesc = A.AchivementDesc and Ts.TargetType='T' and 
    A.AchivementType='T' and 
    (cast(Ts.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(Ts.Year as varchar(5)))=(cast(A.Month as varchar(5))+'-'+cast(A.Year as varchar(5)))
join MST_EmployeeMaster E on TS.TargetDesc=E.Terriory
Group by grouping sets 
    (
        (TS.TargetDesc, Area, Cluster, Region, Segment, TS.Cycle) --lowest level
        , (Area, Cluster, Region, Segment, TS.Cycle)
        , (Cluster, Region, Segment, TS.Cycle)
        , (Region, Segment, TS.Cycle)
        , (Segment, TS.Cycle)
    )
```